# How to call a rest webs service from mysql stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, web-services, rest, stored-procedures

I have a REST web service API which needs to be authenticated before making the call. The API is working fine for calls from java programs.

Now I have a requirement of calling the same service from a MySQL Stored Procedure. How to do that?

Note: Before making the call to the API, it needs to be authenticated with username and password.

This is how its being used in java programs.

```
String getDetails() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        URL url = new URL(baseUrl);
        URLConnection urlConnection = authenticate_api(url);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        reader.close();

        return sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private URLConnection authenticate_api(URL url) throws IOException {
    URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
    String authString = username + ":" + password;
    String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes()));
    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
    return urlConnection;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call a rest API from a stored procedure? Stored procedures are not really meant for such things.

Comment: I need to call the API and retrieve a value and that value is being used further on the procedure. @Shadow

Comment: Let the application do that for you and supply the returned value as a parameter to the stored proc.

Comment: On my investigation I found that its possible to invoke API from SQL server. But I need to do it on MySQL. If SQL is able to do, then why not on MySQL

Comment: I know its a shitty idea but my client wants me to do it in Stored Procedure. I tried convincing but for unknown reasons they are still hanging on for a solution with stored proc.

Comment: 1. It is one thing that a product can do something, it is another thing whether you actually should do that. My challenge is that you should not do this from a stored procedure. Such calls should be in the application layer, not in the database. 2. MySQL and SQL Server are two different products with different features. SQL Server allows you to use .Net assemblies, while MySQL has group_concat() (these are just examples). 3. Probably you can do this from MySQL as well using compiled UDFs, but again, don't do this.