# How to call java method from mysql for every 5 minutes?

Tags: java

How can I call the java service from mysql database using like events,for every 5 minutes i want to call java method from mysql database. is it possible .if it is possible please help to solve this problem ,thanks.

Comment: why call java method write  procedures ,triggers

Comment: You shouldn't do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42529743/how-to-call-a-rest-webs-service-from-mysql-stored-procedure

Comment: wouldn't scheduler will help?